# SSIS Can I Assign a Derived Column Value To A Variable?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I have a data flow task which loads an excel description sheet so that I can parse for a date.  Since the date is inside of a sentence, I need to load in that one line, and parse out the date from that one sentence.

My data flow looks like this:

[image]

So "Parse Sentence" parses the sentence and gets the date string, and "Format Date" formats that string to `YYYY-MM-DD`, and I just put it into a flat file so I can see if I did it correctly.

What I want to do is put that date string into a variable I created "Report Date" so I can pass it into other data flow tasks, and ultimately load it into my database. I've read that you can assign the variable through a script, but I couldn't wrap my head around how to do it exactly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**

"This report provides information regarding members where screenings or tests are recommended.  Data represents claims processed as of 5/30/2017."

This is the only thing I'm loading from the excel sheet, on the first derived column task (Parsing Sentence) I parse through the sentence and extract `5/30/2017`.

Then in the second derived column task (Format Date) I rearrange the string to `2017-5-30`.

**EDIT**

Figured it out, I put the date string into a recordset destination, then outside in the control flow, added a foreach loop container with a script task that assigns the date value to my variable `Report Date`.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us an example of what the sentence looks like?

Comment: You showed a dataflow, which can have more than 1 row. Do you want to store date value of the first row in your variable?

Comment: @dwirony Sure, I've edited my original question to add the sentence.

Comment: @Ferdipux Yes, there's only one thing in the second derived column task (Format Date) and that is `2017-5-30`, I want to just assign that string to a variable I've created called `Report Date`.

Comment: @JLone I need exactly the same thing. Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please find an [example](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/how-to-use-variables-in-script.html) how to set a Variable from a Script Component. It is quite self-explanatory.
In your case you need to read value from your column and store it somewhere, setting `Report Date` variable at PostExecute step.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks.  I'm sure the way you linked was way easier but I just put the value into a Recordset Destination, then a Foreach Loop Container with a Script Task that assigns the `Date` value to the `Report Date` variable.